# Python: Why does class variable get assigned?

Tags: python, oop, properties, instance-variables, class-variables

Here is my code:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = 5

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    value = print("Hello")

a = MyClass()
```

The output is:

```
Hello
```

What I do not understand is why `print("Hello")` gets executed. When I create an instance of the class only the instance variable is set to 0. Why `self.value = 0` calls `value = print("Hello")`?

Can someone explain me this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code evaluates the class when you execute it, and calls the `print` to define the class variable `value`.

The below example shows that it's printed before the instanciation.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = 5

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    value = print("Hello")

print('hi')
a = MyClass()

#output
>>> Hello
>>>hi
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't. That print is executed because it's at the class level itself; the body of a class is executed at the time the class is defined. You would get that output even if you never instantiated MyClass.

Answer (score 2):

Don't let the indentation trick you. `value` ***is not*** an instance variable. `value` is a class variable because it is defined in the class's scope. It's the same as doing:

```
class MyClass:
    value = print("Hello")
    ....
```

Which means that the call to `print` will run at ***class definition time***. In other words, when Python defines `MyClass` it also defines all of the class level variables - including `value`. To define value, it then calls `print`, which is why `Hello` is printed *before* you create an instance of `MyClass`.

If you want only instances of `MyClass` to print `Hello`, put the variable definition inside of the class constructor.

**Side note:** The `print` function returns `None`, so it's seems a bit strange that your assigning the value to a variable. Perhaps you were looking for something like [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) instead?

Answer (score 1):

It does not, drop `a = MyClass()` and it will print `"Hello"` anyway. It executes code in the body when a class is defined:

```
class MyClass:
    print(2 * 2)

# prints 4
```